# Liferay Login page JSP name

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Once the Liferay Start Up page is displayed , there is a Sign-in Hyperlink , and once we click on that Sign-in Hyperlink it will take us to the Page where it will display the actual  Login page.

What is the name of that  JSP page (The Actual page with Email, Password and the Submit Button)?

I am using Liferay 6.1.

Comment: If you are interested in the JSP here it is: \webapps\ROOT\html\portlet\login\login.jsp.

Comment: Thanks , i have a developed a Login page , i will paste this JSP code inside my Portlets  view.jsp . Will this be fine ?? Or should  i use the Hooks concept for this ?? Please advice . Thanks .

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. If you want make you own authetification - I would take another way, see e.g. http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/auto-login

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking of modifying any JSP which is already there in liferay, consider modifying using hooks so that you dont have to restart liferay server since hooks are hot-deployable and easy to manage.

To learn more about hooks follow this link. http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/hoo-4

Answer (score 0):

The login link call login portlet. But you can change default login page, add to portal-ext.properties `auth.login.url=mypageurl`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do in your new login page is to add new fields then using Liferay custom fields will be the way go. You can define custom fields for User and make them editable and then add the into the `login.jsp` file using this tag

```
<div class="exp-ctrl-holder">
    <liferay-ui:custom-attribute 
        className="<%=User.class.getName()%>"
        classPK="<%=0%>" 
        editable="<%=true%>" 
        label="<%=true%>"
        name="FieldName" />
</div>
```

This edit should be done using a hook

or

if you want to add additional logic to the login action then using the  Liferay Extension environment is the best solution.